# How can I print the response from my simple, working POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I have a post method that looks like this:

```
NSString *totalPostURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@registerDevice",self.textUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:totalPostURL]];


NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.finalDict options:0 error:&error];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The code works fine but I have no idea how to print the response from this post. Any suggestions welcome as I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: You need to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol methods, detect when the request has succeeded/completed, and then  get the data. See the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: Thanks, is this the simplest way to do this?

Comment: The synchronous method that Ayan Khan suggested in his answer below is simpler, but it is **synchronous**: it will hang your app while the request completed, if it takes any time. At least if you do it from the main thread (which manages the UI / animations etc.).

Comment: Also, as his linked blog post says, there are third party libraries that wrap and hide the complexity of `NSURLConnection` (among other things). like `ASIHTTPRequest`. If you have the time and effort to spend, and if your app is simple enough, I would try to learn `NSURLConnection` first, to have a better grasp of what's going on. If you are in a hurry and need a quick solution, and don't care to learn, use the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the response as below:

```
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Response:%@",returnString);
```

But Remember as you are a newbie,don't forget to read the tutorial for calling webservices.[Interacting with webservices.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-interacting-with-web-services--mobile-10278)

Answer (score 1):

You get your response in the connection delegate. Look for the method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [receivedData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: receivedData];

    NSData* cData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *WSerror;
    NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:cData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&WSerror];

}
```

Print the responseDic.

Answer (score 0):

@Ayan Khan is right! here i'm adding sample code for http post print response and parsing as JSON if possible, it will handle everything async so your GUI will be refreshing just fine and will not freeze at all - which is important to notice.

```
//POST DATA
NSString *theBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameter=%@",YOUR_VAR_HERE];
NSData *bodyData = [theBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//URL CONFIG
NSString *serverURL = @"https://your-website-here.com";
NSString *downloadUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/your-friendly-url-here/json",serverURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: downloadUrl]];
//POST DATA SETUP
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
//DEBUG MESSAGE
NSLog(@"Trying to call ws %@",downloadUrl);
//EXEC CALL
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
    }
    if (data) {

        //
        // THIS CODE IS FOR PRINTING THE RESPONSE
        //
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response:%@",returnString);

        //PARSE JSON RESPONSE
        NSDictionary *json_response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];

        if ( json_response ) {
            if ( [json_response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
                // do dictionary things
                for ( NSString *key in [json_response allKeys] ) {
                    NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, json_response[key]);
                }
            }
            else if ( [json_response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ) {
                NSLog(@"%@",json_response);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error serializing JSON: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"RAW RESPONSE: %@",data);
            NSString *returnString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response:%@",returnString2);
        }
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps!